# ANTLR zero to multiple occurrence of the same parser rule

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to parse javadoc style comments. How can I indicate that the same parser rule could potentially be triggered zero or more times?

```
doc_comment            :    '/**' (param_declaration)* '*/'         ;

param_declaration      :    OUTERWS '@param' OUTERWS ID OUTERWS;

ID                     :    ('a'..'z')+ ;

OUTERWS                :     ('\n' | '\r' | ' ' |'\t')*;
```

Enclosing the `param_declaration` rule in `()*` doesn't seem to work since it's not a token.

I would expect that:

```
/**
  @param one
  @param two
 */
```

would work. But instead I get: extraneous input '@param' expecting {'*/' which doesn't make sense to me if (param_declaration)* matches zero or more instances. It seems like adding ()* to param_declaration does nothing. Either way:

```
/**
 @param one
*/
```

Works fine; with or without ()*.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is, to match rule `foo` zero or more times, use `(foo)*` or simply `foo*`.

If this is not producing a usable result, then the problem lies somewhere in how you have structured your lexer and/or parser, and to solve it you would need to ask a more specific question and include your grammar along with *specific* inputs and outputs that are not what you hoped, plus a description of the desired output.

**Edit:** Your error with two parameters is occurring because the `param_declaration` rule begins and ends with a required `OUTERWS` token. This means two `OUTERWS` tokens must appear in a row for two parameters to be parsed. This is impossible, because any two sequences of white space characters in the input file would match one long `OUTERWS` token, and that longer token will *always* be used instead of two shorter tokens.

Also note that your `OUTERWS` token is written in such a way that it could match 0 characters. If your input sequence contained a digit, say 0, then the longest token appearing before `0` would be a zero-length `OUTERWS` token. Since the input would not advance as a result of matching 0 characters, this means an input containing a digit should produce an infinitely long stream of empty `OUTERWS` tokens. **The related warning you see when generating code for this grammar is not to be ignored.**

**Edit 2:** Your input can match zero parameters if the comment appears in the form `/***/`. However, if your comment appears in the form `/** */`, you will have an `OUTERWS` token between `/**` and `*/`, which is not allowed by your parser rules when there is no `param_declaration`.

Comment: The above is the complete grammar.

Comment: It doesn't match zero param_definitions either. It appears to only work with one